# Is SQL Injection possible here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, brakeman

I have run a static code analysis tool (brakeman) on a rails app and it has reported some SQL Injection vulnerabilities which I suspect may be false positives. The offending lines look like this:

```
#things_controller.rb

def index
  Thing.select(params[:columns]).where(params[:conditions])
end
```

I can't figure a way to exploit this, but it does seem rather open-ended, is this safe enough (this controller requires admin access anyway) or can it be exploited?

Ruby is 2.0.0-p247,
Rails is 4.0.0

Comment: You're passing unprocessed user input to `where` clause. This is the classic example of SQL injection :)

Comment: Selecting based on any of the columns is not a problem, (admin can do anything), is it possible to subvert the logic to perform other SQL operations (UPDATE, DELETE etc.)

Comment: Postgres driver balks at my attempts, but this is smelly code, at the least.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm worried, however if it can't alter the database then it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rails has some built-in filters for special characters, this is definitely vulnerable:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

If you want to test it yourself, run a full scan with sqlmap using the url of this action with a `conditions` GET parameter

Comment: You would be amazed at how many things sqlmap finds normally :)